# L-stones with quadrat

Tags: combinatorics

Figure A 591014 a gives a square of 25 fields. This figure should be designed with (congruent) L-stones, whereby a special field is removed beforehand.
An L-shaped stone consists of three square shaped L-shaped boxes (see illustration)
A 591014 b).

[image]

a) One of the gray boxes is removed from the square. Show that the figure consisting of the remaining 24 squares can be laid with 8 L stones.

b) One of the white boxes is removed from the square. Show that the figure consisting of the remaining 24 squares can not be laid with 8 L stones.

I just cant solve this and cant find any solution on this question if you could help me, thanks so much and sorry if i have some grammer mistakes since im from Serbia and I'm 16 :)

Comment: For part (a) you just have to trial-and-error.  There are only 3 cases (removing a corner, a middle-of-side square, or the center) and each case is not difficult with just trial and error.  Part (b) I'm not so sure.  Usually these impossibility results involve a parity argument but nothing comes to my mind so far.  However, I think it can be proven by (exhaustive) case analysis.

Comment: Could you please writte me the steps for atleast a) so i can figure out how to do the same for b), if u have time

Answer (score 1):

**Big hint for (b)**

Label the squares of the board like this:

```
A B A B A
C D C D C
A B A B A
C D C D C
A B A B A
```

Each $\mathrm L$-shaped stone tile covers at most one square labeled with an $\mathrm A$.

Comment: +1.  ha!  how can i look at the original picture and still _not_ find this "parity" argument?  ;)

Comment: Ye i tried with it so it means it has to contain atleast A and at some point i understand that it cant be laid but i still cant prove it the right way :/

Answer (score 0):

HINT

(a) is basically trial & error.  here is a sample, the case when the removed gray square is at a corner.  the three positions with the same number = an L-shaped piece.  you just have to try the others 2 cases on your own.  it's not that hard.

```
x 1 1 8 8
2 2 1 8 7 
2 4 4 7 7 
3 4 5 6 6
3 3 5 5 6
```

Comment: Thanks, I made part a) done but what about b) since its now white box